# Is there a way to push new commits to a remote repository without pulling first?

Tags: git, github

I have a github repository that contains quite a few folders that are each have a small self contained project in them, in fact each folder is a module in a course I am taking.

However I am away from home and am using a different machine from where the local repository that matches the remote repository.

I am continuing with the course on a different machine, and I wish to just add those changes to the remote, I am not changing any previous code, basically adding new "directories" to the parent "directory".

I don't want to really have the entire repo on the machine I am using currently, is there a way to push my commits without having to pull the repo first?

I followed the regular git workflow of initializing a local repo, adding the files, committing, adding a remote repo and then pushing.

Git aborted the push informing me I needed to pull first. I know under normal circumstances this is standard operating procedure but want to see if there is anything is to be done.

I have also been searching various variations of my question on google to no avail.

Comment: AFAIK you can't because you need commit history to create a new commit. That being said, I don't understand what's the issue in pulling? You can remove the files afterwards if you don't want to leave them on this computer.

Comment: A good alternative would be to work in GitHub editor directly (Codespaces). No need to do anything locally, you work in a remote environment.

Comment: "is there a way to push my commits without having to pull the repo first?" No. The entire notion constitutes a denial of what Git is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push to a repo that was not pulled. You can work directly on GitHub, which is working directly on a repo that was pulled. If you want to edit files directly on GitHub, then this is how you can do it: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/editing-files